# How can I sort a table by a numerical string as a number when this sorted columns results contain all numbers in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I've been trying to sort a table using a string column that is sometimes populated with real numbers, and I'm using what looks to me like a sound sql query, but it fails and I'm not sure why.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT * FROM chemicals 
WHERE ClientID = '9999'   
ORDER BY CASE WHEN 0 IN   
(SELECT ISNUMERIC([Client Number]) 
 FROM chemicals 
 WHERE ClientID = '9999') 
 THEN [Client Number] 
 ELSE CAST([Client Number] AS float) END ASC, MSDS ASC
```

And I keep getting this error:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type nvarchar to float.
```

It seems like it shouldn't be trying to cast it if it finds that any of the `ClientID`s in the result set aren't numbers, but I guess I'm wrong?

Is there another way I need to be doing this?

Basically, I want to search the result set of `ClientID`s and if they're all numbers, sort in numerical order (8, 9, 10, 11, 12, etc.), but if any `ClientID` in the result set contains non-numerical characters, simply sort by string (which will sometimes result in something like the following: 1, 10, 11, 2, 20, etc.).

***Additional Info***

- The actual data type of `ClientID` is nchar(10)
- Parsable numbers need to be able to include decimals (which is why I'm using float).

Comment: ISNUMERIC() can cause you problems... `SELECT 'TRUE' WHERE ISNUMERIC('$') = 1` and you can replace $ with `1e4` and other values. So you are getting values that this equates to true, but can't be converted to a float. `TRY_CONVERT` is available in 2012 but if not you can use a PATINDEX method. Just tag the version.

Comment: I tried this `SELECT * FROM MasterClientChemicals WHERE ClientID = '1092' ORDER BY CASE WHEN 'true' IN (SELECT 'true' FROM MasterClientChemicals WHERE ISNUMERIC([Client MSDS]) = 0 AND ClientID = '1092') THEN [Client MSDS] ELSE CAST([Client MSDS] AS float) END ASC, MSDS ASC` but it still failed with the same error.

Comment: I was just showing you why you can not use isnumeric for your case

Comment: @scsimon Oh, I see, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm.   Is this what you want?

```
SELECT c.*
FROM chemicals c
WHERE ClientID = '9999'
ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(float, [Client Number]),
         [Client Number],
         MSDS ASC;
```

In pre-2012 versions, you can use a `case` statement instead of `try_convert()`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM chemicals c
WHERE ClientID = '9999'
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([Client Number]) = 1 THEN CONVERT(float, [Client Number]) END),
         [Client Number],
         MSDS ASC;
```

Comment: Be aware that ISNUMERIC can return 1/true even when a CONVERT will fail. I have no clear idea of why they designed it this way, but it can cause no end of headaches.

Comment: Your first code seems to work just fine for me, thank you so very much!